# How to add oauth 2.0 to the Quarkus GraphQL UI?

Tags: oauth-2.0, graphql, quarkus

I have developed a GraphQL API with quarkus (SmallRye GraphQL). I want to protect my GraphQL API using oauth 2.0 (Keykloak as IAM). But I want to use Quarkus GraphQL UI and I do not want to pass headers with access data manually.

How can I enable or improve quarkus GraphQL UI to support oauth 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

If you configure the path to the GraphQL UI to require authentication too, then opening it in your browser will redirect you to the login page. If you then normally log in, your browser will store the session cookie, so when you go back to the GraphQL UI, it will send the cookie along with any GraphQL requests and it should work.

I'd say the GraphQL UI should be protected too, and it wouldn't be proper to inject any user credentials into a page that isn't protected.